# Trouble getting simple php mail script to work on OSX

Tags: php, sendmail

I am trying to get this simple php mail script to send mail to my email addres (mike_minerva@yahoo.com) and I cannot get it to work.  I set my sendmail_path in php.ini to the right folder (/etc/sbin/sendmail) but that did not seem to help.  What else could I be missing?  The script always returns failure.

```
<?php
$to = "mike_minerva@yahoo.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From: $from";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
    echo "Mail Sent.";
else
    echo "failure";
?>
```

Comment: Check your various error logs to see if the message made it to sendmail.  Can you send mail from the command line?

Comment: When I tried doing sendmail at the command line it gave this error:
sendmail: warning: valid_hostname: numeric hostname: 199.45.162.68.9
sendmail: fatal: file /etc/postfix/main.cf: parameter mydomain: bad parameter value: 199.45.162.68.9
I set this to the same address as my pathname (the address for my pop server) and it stopped giving the message and returned mail sent, but the mail never arrived.  Thanks for your suggestion.  Have  another one?

Comment: Yes but how?  No one answered the question.  I can't accept a comment....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else comes to this question via google, another main cause of php mail not working is that the function is blocked on many servers due to the danger of outgoing spam.

There are some good smtp mail classes out there that are very easy to use. I only use mail() for debugging purposes... almost never in a live environment.

Answer (score 1):

SwiftMailer is a good library for the purpose of authenticating to your SMTP server to send mail.

http://swiftmailer.org/

Answer (score 1):

try to use PEAR MAIL package.